# Lower and upper index in a sorted vector

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, lower-bound, upperbound

I have a vector with timestamps as following:

```
1521753105.031429052352905
1521753105.081429004669189
1521753105.131428956985474
1521753105.181428909301758
1521753105.231429100036621
1521753105.281429052352905
1521753105.331429004669189
1521753105.381428956985474
1521753105.431428909301758
1521753105.481429100036621
1521753105.531429052352905
1521753105.581429004669189
```

The current time is:

```
1521753105.231428861618042
```

which is in between the 4th and 5th values.

[image: The Values lies between two values]

How to determine the lower and upper index to the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner trick!

```
A=%[your numbers]
v=%the value to find its position

braket=find(sort([A,v])==v)+[-1 0]
```

Assumes that `A` was sorted originally, of course

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Ander's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62873745/5698672):

[`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) first greater timestamp than your current timestamp. Find last smaller timestamp by subtracting one.

```
bracket = find(A>v,1) + [-1, 0];
```

Comment: This one is more efficient than mine ;)